# Deploy Vue.js application to gitlab pages even though deployment is successful nothing is displayed

Tags: vuejs2, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, vue-cli-3

I am trying to deploy a sample Vue.js application to Gitlab pages but even though deployment has passed successfully nothing is rendered when I try to hit the served URL.

Here is my deployment code(.gitlab-ci.yml):

```
pages:
 image: node:latest
 stage: deploy
 script:
  - npm install --progress=false
  - npm run build
  - mkdir .public
  - cp -r dist/* .public
  - mv .public public
 artifacts:
  expire_in: 1 week
  paths:
   - public
 only:
  - master
```

I tried to locally serve the pages after `npm run build` from the `/dist` folder and its working all fine. I am not sure if there are any issues in my deployment script in Gitlab.

How do I get my application running in Gitlab pages?

I am using `vuejs2`and `vue-cli-3` for bundling the scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue with my code. The `public` folder contained duplicate data due to which it was not rendering the application properly.

Here is the working version of the deployment script:

```
pages:
 image: node:latest
 stage: deploy
 script:
  - npm install --progress=false
  - npm run build
  - rm -rf public
  - mkdir public
  - cp -r dist/* public
 artifacts:
  expire_in: 1 week
  paths:
  - public
 only:
  - master
```

After pipeline process is completed access the Gitlab pages of your repository. You should see the app rendering as expected.